# Add labelText over BoxDecoration for Container (as TextField)

Tags: flutter

TextField has a nice way of placing a text label over its box decoration.

[image: out]

with:

```
TextField(
        onTap: onTap,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "XP",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
          ),
        ));
```

Is there  way to achieve the same for other BoxDecoration for a Container? For example, I'd like to specify the label "XP":

```
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            border: Border.all(color: color, width: 2.0),
            labelText: Text("XP"),   // No such attribute
          ),
          child: child,
        ),
```

... but Flutter doesn't provide labelText for `BoxDecoration` (only for `InputDecoration`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to add a MabelText over BoxDecoration for Container like a TextField:

Came across this and figured it might help.
Use the TextField and set the readOnly to 'True';
// This will disable the tap feature leaving the user unable to change the items within but you can display the results as needed.

In my example, I have the results set in the stateless widget to return the results from a method.

```
class TextField_resultBx extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextField_resultBx({
    Key? key,
    required this.boxResultTitle,
    required this.borderLabelTextBox,
    required this.displayBoxResult,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String boxResultTitle;
  final String borderLabelTextBox;
  final String displayBoxResult;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            boxResultTitle,
            textScaleFactor: 1.2,
            softWrap: true,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          // Results Box 1:
          TextField(
            // enabled: true,
            readOnly: true,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: kCalLabelColor,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabled: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              // Border Label TextBox 1
              labelText: borderLabelTextBox,
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: kCalLabelColor,
              ),
              hintText: displayBoxResult,

              hintMaxLines: 2,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: kEnbBorderSide,
                borderRadius: kCalOutlineBorderRad,
              ),
              focusedBorder: kFocusedBorder,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Container label Text similar to Textfield labels]

Comment: NOT RELATED. But how was the 3d elevated design done? can you share it?

Answer (score 32):

You can use InputDecorator

```dart
Container(
  child: InputDecorator(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'XP',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Text('content goes here'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: the text overlaps with the border.

Answer (score 7):

i will go with ans of
[Luxiriox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14093885/luxariox)

just one change pass border in enableBorder

```dart
Container(
  child: InputDecorator(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'XP',
      enableBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Text('content goes here'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Perfect result!

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you have to do it a bit differently using Stack

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 80,
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: Container(
          width: 250,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 10,
        bottom: 40,
        child: Container(color: Colors.white, child: Text('XP')),
      )
    ],
  )
```

OUTPUT

[image]

You can also create a custom container widget and call it same way as your container

MY CUSTOM CONTAINER

```
class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final BoxDecoration decoration;

  const CustomContainer({this.labelText, this.decoration});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 80,
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(width: 250, height: 50, decoration: decoration),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 10,
          bottom: 40,
          child: Container(color: Colors.white, child: Text('XP')),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

CALL IT WHEREVER YOU WANT

```
CustomContainer(
        labelText: 'XP',
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: how to make the height auto ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do as follows using position

```
Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 88,
                              width: 88,
                              child: ImagePickerWidget(
                                diameter: 180,
                                initialImage: "${snapshot.data['imagePath']}",
                                shape: ImagePickerWidgetShape
                                    .circle, // isEditable: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              left: 5,
                              bottom: 28,
                              child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Double Tap\nto Call',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                  )),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
```